# C#. Хочу реализовать обобщенный Math.Lerp()

Tags: unity3d, математика

Мне нужен универсальный `Math.Lerp`, чтобы он работал как с `float`, так и с `Vector` (по части Unity).

Вот пример кода, который, я уверен, будет работать, но у компилятора возникают трудности, чтобы понять это.

```
public static T Lerp<T>(T a, T b, float t)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
    {
        return Mathf.Lerp(a, b, t);
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Vector3))
    {
        return Vector3.Lerp(a, b, t);
    }
    
    throw new Exception("Вы пытаетесь сгладить не числовой тип!");
}
```

На что он жалуется? А вот:

Для float: `Argument type 'T' is not assignable to parameter type 'float'`

Для Vector3: `Argument type 'T' is not assignable to parameter type 'UnityEngine.Vector3'`

Думаю, если прочитать этот кусок кода станет понятно. Что он не понимает, что, после условия передаваемый T - 100%, например, float.

Вот в чем и вопрос - как сделать так, что бы компилятор понял мою идею? Может быть есть какой то более простой или, наоборот, изощрённый способ? Буду рад любым идеям.

Comment: По идее хватит a is float для проверки

Comment: М.. Нет. Такой вариант не проходит

Answer (score 0):

Для вас подойдёт [Перегрузка методов](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.5.php).

Просто объявите 2 метода с одним названием, но разной сигнатурой:

```cs
public static float Lerp(float a, float b, float v)
{
    return Math.Lerp(a, b, v);
}

public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float v)
{
    return Vector3.Lerp(a, b, v);
}
```

Если же вы хотите узнать почему ваш пример не работает, напишите в комментариях

Comment: Конечно, я знаю что такое перегрузки. Забыл указать это в вопросе.
Это решение не подходит, по некоторой причине, которая появляется в другом классе.

Comment: @Sqeje В таком случае сейчас уточню ответ, но хотелось бы узнать, что это за причина?

Comment: Из другого класса мне необходима вызывать Lerp по структуре: Lerp<T>

Comment: К сожалению C# - строго типизированный язык... И такие приколы прокатят только через костыли. Более чем уверен, что это можно сделать и нормальным способом. Хотелось бы увидеть больше кода